# Storekit 2 API missing in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, storekit

I have a legacy Xamarin.iOS app.
This app uses store kit. to purchase products, but the method used is marked as obsolete.
Here is the obsolete method used by the legacy app :

```
SKPayment.PaymentWithProduct(_subscription);
```

The compiler tells me this method is obsolete, and I should use "From Product" instead. I guess this means I should use the new Storekit 2 "Purchase" method that is found on the product class, as shown below **IN Swift language**:

```
 let result = try await product.purchase()
```

But the issue is, I can't find this method in the SKProduct class in Xamarin.iOS
How should I do please ?

Comment: check this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/in-app-purchasing/purchasing-consumable-products

Answer (score 1):

StoreKit2 is not available in xamarin

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/431

[image]